# view model with IList<subView Model> add data failed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a view model DetailViewModel contains one IList of a sub view model EntryDetailViewModel.

```
public class DetailViewModel
{
    [NotMapped]
    [JsonIgnore]
    private IList<EntryDetailViewModel> _entries;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public new IList<EntryDetailViewModel> Entries
    {
        get
        {
            if (_entries == null)
                _entries = new List<=EntryDetailViewModel>();

            return _entries.Where(m => !m.Deleted).ToList();
        }
        set => _entries = value;
    }
}
```

My issue is when adding a EntryDetailViewModel entryDetailModel into the collection, the collection simply remains count = 0.

```
detailModel.Entries.Add(entryDetailModel);
```

[image]

Any ideas? Is it because entryDetailModel at the moment has no Id so it cannot be added? Or what can it be?

**Additional Info**

I tried query an existing DetailViewModel dvm1, and a existing EntryDetailViewModel from another DetailViewModel to add into dvm1, it also failed. Does that mean I can't add view model into another view model?

Comment: Does adding an entry via debug window work?

Comment: I have not tried it but the main model detailMode was added into the DB

Comment: I'm still learning, but I noticed you have declared your property as `public new`. I believe `new` is used like this when you have the same property declared in the base class, only the class in your example is not derived from anything. Could this be causing a problem? It's not something I've ever used so not sure, just thought it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @Daniel The new IList is used to assign values to _entries in case it does not exist since it is a table for additional data, which is not required.

Comment: @joseph.c But isn't that handled by `if (_entries == null) _entries = new List<=EntryDetailViewModel>();`? The use of `new` in a property declaration asserts that you are aware that the member being modified hides a member that is inherited from the base class. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords

Comment: @Daniel oh now I know what I missed, this viewmodel actually derived from another viewmodel and that's why there's a new

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it won't work that way.

When you call:

```
detailModel.Entries.Add(entryDetailModel);
```

This triggers the Getter for your Entries, which is doing this:

```
return _entries.Where(m => !m.Deleted).ToList();
```

_entries may have been set to a new `List<Entry>` however, by returning the `.Where(...).ToList()`, the getter will return a *newly initialized* list containing just non-deleted entries. You're adding to that temporary list of results, not _entries.

If you want your Getters to filter only undeleted rows, that is fine, but you should consider a more of a DDD approach:

```
[NotMapped]
[JsonIgnore]
private IList<EntryDetailViewModel> _entries = new List<EntryDetailViewModel>();

[JsonIgnore]
public new IReadOnlyList<EntryDetailViewModel> Entries
{
    get
    {
        return _entries.Where(m => !m.Deleted).ToList().AsReadOnly();
    }
}

public void AddEntry(EntryDetailViewModel entry)
{
    // TODO: Validate entry doesn't already exist, is complete/valid...
    // then...

    _entries.Add(entry);
}
```

With collection sets it's beneficial to initialize them on creation to avoid needing that extra boiler plate to check for null or constructor initialization. Then the getter is marked as a ReadOnlyList (or ReadOnlyCollection) which returns your filtered data. Using ReadOnly variants isn't required but it gives your future consumers at least some warning that says "Hey, you shouldn't try and modify this collection." DDD involves exposing suitable add/update/delete methods to regulate when and how the state of this object can be changed.  There is no Setter for this collection so it cannot be overwritten by some rogue code added later. This involves planning out methods to serve as actions to regulate how state is modified rather than relying on setters.

Comment: Thanks for your help and thorough explanation! I will give this a try

Comment: Thank you so so much, this fixed my issue!

Comment: I'm sorry but this turns out to not work when trying to read the data into this viewmodel. The entry will always be a new list.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Steve Py for pointing out calling model.entries.add(entry) will always trigger the getter, which result to returning a new list every time.

However, the solution will always return a new list of the viewmodel when query and mapped. My original code doesn't post this issue, so I integrated them together by adding the AddEntry function, which will not trigger the getter and still able to query all the necessary data. My solution is down below.

```
[AutoMap(typeof(Manifest), ReverseMap = true)]
public class ViewModel
{
    ......other stuff

    [NotMapped]
    [JsonIgnore]
    private IList<EntryViewModel> _entries;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual IList<EntryViewModel> Entries
    {
        get
        {
            if (_entries == null)
                _entries = new List<EntryViewModel>();

            return _entries.Where(m => !m.Deleted).ToList();
        }
        set => _entries = value;
    }

    public void AddEntry(EntryViewModel entry)
    {
        _entries.Add(entry);
    }
}

[AutoMap(typeof(Manifest), ReverseMap = true)]
public class DetailViewModel : ViewModel
{
    ......other stuff

    [NotMapped]
    [JsonIgnore]
    private IList<EntryDetailViewModel> _entries;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public new IList<EntryDetailViewModel> Entries
    {
        get
        {
            if (_entries == null)
                _entries = new List<EntryDetailViewModel>();

            return _entries.Where(m => !m.Deleted).ToList();
        }
        set => _entries = value;
    }

    public void AddEntry(EntryDetailViewModel entry)
    {
        _entries.Add(entry);
    }
}
```